# How to center text in div and hr together?

Tags: html, css, position, text-alignment

I want to put some text inside of my container `<div>` and also center that text.

```css
.hr {
  background: green;
  height: 50px; margin: 65px 0; width: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hr"></div>
```

An image of how my project looks like:

[image]

My code as an image:

[image]

Comment: post your code as snippet **not** as image!

Comment: It is quite hard to understand what you want from images and code is barely readible

Comment: I wanna put and center text in my green container. To create the container i used hr and div:

CSS:
.hr {
background:url(https://userscontent2.emaze.com/images/ac315fff-308a-4fc6-9f69-1a60c07df893/988a7b30caade3fa457f9941d5880985.jpg);
height: 50px;
margin: 65px 0;
width: 3000px;
}

HTML:
<div class="hr"></div>

Comment: could you please give the code that you are using

Comment: html:  <div class="hr"> </div>
css: .hr {
background:url(https://userscontent2.emaze.com/images/ac315fff-308a-4fc6-9f69-1a60c07df893/988a7b30caade3fa457f9941d5880985.jpg);
height: 50px;
margin: 65px 0;
width: 3000px;
}

Answer (score 1):

I have just changed image by a color and added a `text-align:center`

```css
.hr { 
  background:#f00; 
  height: 50px; 
  margin: 65px 0; 
  width: 3000px; 
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="hr"><span>text</span> </div>
```

is that you looking for?

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply! That is not the exact thing im looking for but my major problem is that my text is not centered even if i am using the tag. Any advices?

Comment: @Plamen : couldn't get you, by using the `text-align:center` tag the text aligned to center of the div you can see that on the snippet

Comment: my problem is that when i enter the text it is not centered(sample heading): http://imgur.com/2pnN8ZJ.

These are my codes:
html:  <div class="hr">
<h2 style="text-align:center;float:center"> Sample Heading</h2>
</div>

css:
.hr {
background:url(https://userscontent2.emaze.com/images/ac315fff-308a-4fc6-9f69-1a60c07df893/988a7b30caade3fa457f9941d5880985.jpg);
height: 50px;
margin: 65px 0;
width: 3000px;

}

Comment: @Plamen : the problem is with the width that you set could you please set the width to `100%` instead of `3000px`

Comment: Yep i solved the problem using this solution! The problem was that container's width was greater than the browser window.